# How to Plot confidence intervals in this particular population proportion?

Tags: pandas, dataframe, confidence-interval, scipy.stats

I am trying to plot a confidence interval for df called 'Sex'. But the confidence interval seems to touch the x axis and it does'nt seem to be right.Can someone help me here?

The dataframe is basically binary with either Male or Female.

[This is the barplot I got](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eTlxN.png)

```
This is the code I used:

    p = df['Sex'].value_counts(normalize=True)
n = len(df)
se = np.sqrt(p * (1 - p) / n)
z = stats.norm.ppf(0.957)  # Z-score for 95% confidence level
ci_lower = p - z * se
ci_upper = p + z * se


fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.bar(p.index, p.values)
ax.errorbar(p.index, p.values, yerr=[ci_lower, ci_upper],ecolor='red', fmt='none', capsize=10)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do this:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy import stats

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.choice(['Male', 'Female'], size=1000, p=[0.4, 0.6]), columns=['Sex'])

p = df['Sex'].value_counts(normalize=True)
n = len(df)
se = np.sqrt(p * (1 - p) / n)
z = stats.norm.ppf(0.957)  # Z-score for 95% confidence level
ci_lower = np.maximum(p - z * se, 0)  # Adjust lower limit to be 0 if it's below 0
ci_upper = p + z * se

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.bar(p.index, p.values)
ax.errorbar(p.index, p.values, yerr=[ci_lower, ci_upper], ecolor='red', fmt='none', capsize=10)
plt.show()
```

which gives

[image]